# make install error when compiling a program with cuda

Tags: drivers, installation, compile, make, cmake

I am trying to compile [THIS](https://github.com/fireice-uk/xmr-stak) program for my ubuntu system using the master source. I have installed the AMDGPU-PRO drivers and the [AMD 3.0 SDK](https://developer.amd.com/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/) drivers via the basic install instructions on AMDs website.

I have also installed the [CUDA toolkit](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=1604&target_type=debnetwork) since I would like the program to work with AMD & NVIDIA GPUs. The CUDA toolkit was installed by doing the following:

```
`sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1604_9.1.85-1_amd64.deb`
`sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub`
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install cuda`
```

I followed [THESE](https://github.com/fireice-uk/xmr-stak/blob/master/doc/compile_Linux.md) compiling instructions on github.

```
# Ubuntu / Debian
sudo apt install libmicrohttpd-dev libssl-dev cmake build-essential libhwloc-dev
git clone https://github.com/fireice-uk/xmr-stak.git
mkdir xmr-stak/build
cd xmr-stak/build
cmake ..
make install
```

Everything seems to work OK until I run the "sudo make install" command which returns the below errors.

```
[ 70%] Building NVCC (Device) object CMakeFiles/xmrstak_cuda_backend.dir/xmrstak/backend/nvidia/nvcc_code/xmrstak_cuda_backend_generated_cuda_extra.cu.o
/home/miner1/xmr-stak/xmrstak/backend/nvidia/nvcc_code/cuda_extra.cu:9:32: fatal error: device_functions.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
CMake Error at xmrstak_cuda_backend_generated_cuda_extra.cu.o.cmake:207 (message):
  Error generating
  /home/miner1/xmr-stak/build/CMakeFiles/xmrstak_cuda_backend.dir/xmrstak/backend/nvidia/nvcc_code/./xmrstak_cuda_backend_generated_cuda_extra.cu.o


CMakeFiles/xmrstak_cuda_backend.dir/build.make:70: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/xmrstak_cuda_backend.dir/xmrstak/backend/nvidia/nvcc_code/xmrstak_cuda_backend_generated_cuda_extra.cu.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/xmrstak_cuda_backend.dir/xmrstak/backend/nvidia/nvcc_code/xmrstak_cuda_backend_generated_cuda_extra.cu.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:68: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/xmrstak_cuda_backend.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/xmrstak_cuda_backend.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:127: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

It seems like the issue has to do with CUDA being unable to locate a file. I am unsure if this is a path error or a gcc version error. I have tried reinstalling gcc, but with no luck. The program does compile correctly when used without CUDA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same error with CUDA 9.1, but with CUDA 9.0 everything is ok. Try to uninstall CUDA 9.1 and install CUDA 9.0, it must help you to compile xmr-stak.

```
sudo apt-get remove cuda
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install cuda-9.0
```

Comment: seems to be stuck on the 70% mark.  Building NVCC (Device) object CMakeFiles/xmrstak_cuda_backend.dir/xmrstak/backend/nvidia/nvcc_code/xmrstak_cuda_backend_generated_cuda_extra.cu.o

Comment: i will update if it moves/works